# Delay Attaching a gravity in an Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I have this ball that can move from left to right and it also have a gravity attached to it that will increase overtime.
PROBLEM : How do i delay attaching/adding the gravity to the object for like 3 seconds.
EXPECTATION : At the start i can still move the ball from left to right without gravity so same position at the y-axis but after 3 seconds the ball will have the gravity and starts to fall down.

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Init
    public Vector2 speedMinMax;
    public Vector2 gravityMinMax;
    float speed;
    float move;
    float gravity;
    float halfPlayerWidth;
    private float screenHalfWidthInWorldUnit;
    //Components
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;

    void Awake()
    {
        rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        SpawnPlayer();
        halfPlayerWidth = transform.localScale.x / 2f;
        screenHalfWidthInWorldUnit = Camera.main.aspect * Camera.main.orthographicSize + halfPlayerWidth;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        IncreaseGravity();
        PlayerBounds();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        PlayerInput();
    }

    void SpawnPlayer()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(0, Camera.main.orthographicSize - transform.localScale.y - 2f);
    }

    void PlayerInput()
    {
        //PlayerInput
        //Keyboard
        speed = Mathf.Lerp(speedMinMax.x, speedMinMax.y, Difficulty.GetDifficultyPercent());
        move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
    }
    
    void IncreaseGravity()
    {
        gravity = Mathf.Lerp(gravityMinMax.x, gravityMinMax.y, Difficulty.GetDifficultyPercent());
        rigidbody2D.gravityScale = gravity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[RigidBody2D.gravityScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-gravityScale.html) component controls the gravity of attached object. You can create a coroutine and set **gravityScale** to 0 there for disabling. After 3 second set it to old or desired value.
`

```
IEnumerator WaitForGravity()
 {
     rigidbody2d.gravityScale = 0;
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
     rigidbody2d.gravityScale = 1;
 }
```

At start function fire this coroutine.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitForGravity());
}
```